# How to get basic Shopify GraphQL Admin API working with nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, graphql, shopify, node-fetch, shopify-api

I had a very frustrating evening yesterday, trying to get the basic Shopify GraphQL Admin API example working with nodeJS. The original Shopify example code is [here](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/graphql-with-node-and-express).

The problem is that my code returns a status 400 - Bad Request.

I have enabled a "private App" on my store and enabled all the APIs with read access. I carefully copied the apiKey, accessToken and store name from Shopify.

Can anyone point out if there is something wrong with my code? Many thanks.

Code:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const apiKey = 'xxxx';
const accessToken = 'yyyy';
const store = 'zzzz';
const hostName = store + '.myshopify.com';
const apiVersion = '2021-01';
const apiLocation = '/admin/api/';

const rootUrl = 'https://' + apiKey + ':' + accessToken + '@' + hostName + apiLocation + apiVersion + '/';

const shopGraphQl = 'https://' + hostName + apiLocation + apiVersion + '/graphql.json';
//const shopGraphQl2 = rootUrl + 'graphql.json';
//const urlTest = rootUrl + 'orders.json';

const url = shopGraphQl;

const body = {
    query: `{
        shop {
            name
          }
      }`
};

fetch   (
    url,
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Shopify-Access-Token" : accessToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            body
        })
    }
)
.then(res => {
    console.log('status = ' + res.status + ' , ' + res.statusText);
})
.then(json => {
    console.log("data returned:\n", json);
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));;
```

Comment: If you're gonna `JSON.stringify` `body.query`, why wrap it as a template string

Comment: Ok I see it's that way in the docs

Comment: The only difference I am seeing between what you have and the docs is that the docs aren't defining an api version, `apiVersion`, '2021-01'

Comment: Yes, I tried multiple permutations on the URL. Still no luck

Comment: Have you explicitly set it to, `https://<shop>.myshopify.com/admin/api/graphql.json` using your shop name?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too... the answer below has fixed the error for me :) Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are sending body incorrectly. The way you are sending your body results in  `{body: { query: { shop { name } } } }`

Instead of:

```js
body: JSON.stringify({body})
```

change it to:

```js
body: JSON.stringify(body)
```

#### Receiving data from fetch

You have noticed that your console.log statement, `console.log("data returned:\n", json);` is returning `undefined`. The reason for this is that you need to extract the json from the response (`res.json()`).

```js
return fetch (
    url,
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Shopify-Access-Token" : accessToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }
)
.then(res => {
    console.log(`status = ${res.status}, ${res.statusText}`);
    return res.json();
})
.then(json => {
    console.log("data returned:\n", json);
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));;
```

Here is a decent reference on using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Thank you very much! That has solved it and given me the status 200 now.

Comment: Out of interest: Would you also know why I get returned Promise { <pending> }
data returned:
 undefined

Comment: You should be returning the promise from your fetch: `return fetch(url,...`. where are your running this from that you are seeing that result?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will dig into this later today. Very much appreciated. This function is the only function run in my test program.

Comment: I am assuming you are running this from the NodeJS REPL (maybe `node filename.js`). Fetch returns a promise so you are seeing that. and no data is return so its undefined

Comment: Yes run straight from NodeJS. Does this indicate that the server is simply returning no data?

Comment: Your not getting your JSON data from fetch. I will add it to the answer